# i need to insert employee and service id in a table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to insert employee id and service id into a new table addservice.i wrote a function add in my controller page where i get my employee id from the session and service id from the service table from the uri.
In controller

```
public function add()
    {
    $this->load->library('session');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data_to_store = array('employee_id'=>$taxdetails['total'],
    'service_id'=>$id);
    $this->selected_model->store_employee($data_to_store);
                     $data['main_content'] = 'admin/selected/list';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
```

in model:
this is my model file where wrote the code to insert the employee id and service id.

```
public function store_employee($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('addservice', $data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

in view page

```
<div class="container top">

      <ul class="breadcrumb">
         <li>
          <a href="http://localhost/elfanto/elfanto_billing/admin/addservice">
            Admin          </a> 
          <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          Service        </li>
      </ul>


     <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 columns">
          <div >

            <?php

            $attributes = array('class' => 'form-inline reset-margin', 'id' => 'myform');

            $options_manufacture = array(0 => "all");
            foreach ($category as $row)
            {
              $options_manufacture[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
            }
            //save the columns names in a array that we will use as filter         
            $options_products = array();    
            foreach ($service as $array) {
              foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $options_products[$key] = $key;
              }
              break;
            }


            ?>

          </div>

          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="header">Service id</th>
                <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">Service name </th>
                <th class="green header">Service catogary</th>
                <th class="red header">Service tax</th>
                <th class="red header">Service length</th>
                <th class="red header">Service price</th>
                <th class="red header">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach($service as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_tax'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_length'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_price'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/selected/add/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Add service</a>  

                </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>      
            </tbody>
          </table>
 <a href='admin/employee/add' class="btn btn-info">Continue as chair renter</a> 
          <?php echo '<div class="pagination">'.$this->pagination->create_links().'</div>'; ?>

      </div>
    </div>
```

this code doesnt work for. i am not able to resolve my problem can someone correct my code.

Comment: what do you mean by does not work?

Comment: i dont get any error i am getting a white page

Comment: In your controller, what is `$taxdetails`?

Comment: it is an session variable which i have in another controller employee_controller

Comment: So when you click the "Add service" button, you just get a white screen, without the data been inserted?

Comment: Please update your post with your routes.php because your link does not seem to match any of the function you have in there.

Comment: admin/selected/add is the path to reach add function in the controller

Answer (score 0):

In your url try adding index.php after projectname http://localhost/elfanto/index.php/elfanto_billing/admin/addservice and the link does not match the functions.

**Example**

`http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/add/`

First I would recommend auto load the session library to get

To get any set session userdata you need to do some thing like but do not know how you set your sessions.

`$this->session->userdata('total')`

Controller Function

```
public function add() {
    $this->selected_model->store_employee();

    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/selected/list';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

}
```

Model Function

```
public function store_employee()
{

    $data = array(
        'employee_id' => $this->session->userdata('total'),
        'service_id' => $this->uri->segment(4)
    );

    $this->db->insert('addservice', $data);

}
```

if session set in array()

```
$taxdetails = $this->session->userdata('some_array_name');

$taxdetails['total']
```

Function example 2

```
public function store_employee()
{

$taxdetails = $this->session->userdata('some_array_name');

    $data = array(
        'employee_id' => $taxdetails['total'],
        'service_id' => $this->uri->segment(4)
    );

    $this->db->insert('addservice', $data);

}
```